# Getting Blank rectangle in Highcharts version 6.2

Tags: jquery, angular, highcharts

I was previously running Highcharts 4.1.10 with jQuery 2.1.3 in my angular js web application and it worked perfectly. Now I am trying to move to latest version of Highcharts 6.2.0, but now i see a black rectangle in the UI. I am not using any jQuery easing functions in my UI. Is there any fix for this issue?

I have attached my package.json for the same. Let me know if I have missed something.

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "3.0.8",
  "keywords": [
    "highcharts",
  ],
  "private": true,
  "cpu": [
    "x64"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": "^6.9.0",
    "npm": "^3.10.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.15",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.15",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.15",
    "angular-route": "1.3.15",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.15",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "0.12.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "hi-session-monitor": "1.0.4",
    "highcharts": "4.1.10",
    "jquery": "2.1.3",
    "ui-select": "0.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.15",
    "bower": "latest",
    "clean-css-cli": "4.1.10",
    "del-cli": "1.1.0",
    "eslint": "4.7.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "12.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "htmlhint": "0.9.13",
    "htmlprocessor": "0.2.6",
    "jasmine": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jsdoc": "3.5.5",
    "js-beautify": "1.7.3",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "1.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "markdownlint": "0.6.1",
    "stylelint": "8.1.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
    "uglify-js": "2.8.29"
  }
}
```

Comment: add a jsfiddle for more response

Comment: any errors in the console ?

Comment: @AIqbal no, i dont see any errors in console.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor (jsfiddle)? Try to simplify this example, perhaps this issue occurs even without the Angular framework. Or at least show the chart code.

Comment: I have not added the full code but only the code that uses the chart service.https://jsfiddle.net/sumanlucky5/gfyep8an/2/

Comment: There are too many undefined variables in that fiddle to be helpful. There are too many factors that could be cause your problem to solve without a lot more detail or troubleshooting on your end, or a full working example.